# Kafka connect mongoDB connector fail to convert a document containing an Array of String

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have the following connector configuration:

```
{
  "name": "request-closed-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "4",
    "connection.uri": "@@mongoDB-uri@@",
    "database": "Trade",
    "collection": "RequestClosed",
    "topic.namespace.map":"{\"Trade.RequestClosed\":\"RequestClosed\"}",
    "copy.existing":"true",
    "output.format.value": "schema",
    "output.schema.value": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"RequestClosed\",\"namespace\":\"trades\",\"doc\":\"Records for RequestClosed.\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"orderId\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}},{\"name\":\"externalOrderIds\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"avro.java.string\":\"String\"}},\"default\":[]}]}",
    "startup.mode.copy.existing.max.threads":"8",
    "offset.partition.name":"request-closed-source.2"
  }
}
```

But when I run it over my collection containing only one document such as:

```
{
 "orderId": "orderId1",
 "externalOrderIds": ["1", "2"]
}
```

I have the following error:

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.SchemaBuilderException: Invalid
> default value
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Invalid Java object for
> schema with type STRING: class java.util.ArrayList

In order to discover what was wrong I tried the following:

- Insert a document with a String.
- Insert a document with empty array.
- Insert a document with an array containing one String.
- Insert a document with no externalOrderIds field.
- Set the default value of the avro schema to ["test"].
- Remove the default field from the schema declaration.

But I got the same error every time.